# how do you access and control ubuntu vps via desktop?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vps

how do you control your webserver vps using a remote desktop?

for example, I am on ubuntu, is it possible to control the ubuntu gui on the vps server?

I've done it with windows server using the Remote Desktop Client in accessories but I don't know how to do this for linux servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you'd need a gui to control a server - the usual way is to use ssh and putty(or some other ssh client) and cli. That said, there's a few other alternatives to VNC that are worth looking at if you DO need a graphical desktop accessed remotely

The usual way to do graphical things remotely on linux is with [x forwarding](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html) - you can use a x client, and simply export the window to your own system with ssh -X (hostname) (program), or export the entire desktop with xdmp. The advantage with this is, you can pretty much use software that comes built into any linux system.

There's also some alternate remote access such as [nomachine's nx or its derivatives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) that are worth looking at - in my experience nx is faster than x forwarding or VNC by quite a bit, and is secure since its ssh tunneled. It also lets you disconnect but keep persistent sessions running , even seperate ones, rather than tieing you to a single session as VNC does.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done with [`VNC`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC).